# Ubuntu OS selection screen

Tags: 12.04, windows

After I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual boot with windows 7 from USB ( not from `wubi.exe`) whenever I boot my system I was taken to the Ubuntu OS selection screen which shows ( selection for Ubuntu generic, Ubuntu generic recovery , windows loader, memory test etc). I need to change it to Windows OS selection screen which shows only two options to select from ( windows 7 and Ubuntu). Any way to change it ???

Comment: Try following some of the dual-boot guides. Back when I was dual booting, there was some sort of a windows app to customize the "selection screen".

Answer (score 0):

You can try grub-customizer. You have to add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) to ubuntu and then install it. (See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) for information on PPA safety.)

From terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then launch it and you should be able to set windows as main selection and to hide what you want. It's not to hard to use.

Comment: What if i uninstall Ubuntu( in future if I give ma laptop to somebody) will I get any grub error,I had a system with BossLinux OS and Windows OS i formated the partition of Boss OS in windows disk management but after that whenever i booted my system i was shown grub error and system bootloops which i fixed using Windows live CD. I understand that if I have windows OS selection screen the grub error wont be happening.